# How to find DB created in SQLite

Tags: database, r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm using this code to load the data from DB `ontime` into the data frame in R.

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

ontime <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "ontime.sqlite3")
from_db <- function(sql) {
  dbGetQuery(ontime, sql)
}

from_db("select count(*), tailnum from ontime group by tailnum")

tails <- from_db("select distinct tailnum from ontime")
```

However, it seems that R cannot find DB `ontime` that I created from SQLite shell.

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such table: ontime
```

I tried to search `ontime` on disk, but I didn't find it. I also double-checked that this DB exists by using `select * from ontime` command. So, where is this DB stored on disk and how can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite databases are a single file on disk.  In this case you already named it in your connection: `"ontime.sqlite3"`.

The error message occurs because your query

```
select count(*), tailnum from ontime group by tailnum
```

is asking for data in a **table** named `ontime` (inside the `ontime` DB), and presumably there is no table with that name.

Comment: That's really strange. I created a table in SQLite shell, then closed the shell and reopened it again. Now I cannot find the table. Should I save all the tables with some "save" command before exiting the shell?

Comment: Not sure what happened to you there, but I find the easiest way to work with SQLite is with Firefox SQLite manager. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/